# HTML error when using color= in font

Tags: html

I am completely new to coding and have a error with this script:

```
<font face=arial color= red>
```

It is supposed to turn the text red

Comment: What's the error? How do you know it's not working? Please provide more information

Comment: You probably want to find a more modern tutorial than whatever you're following there. These days you'd typically not use a `font` element to change the colour of some text. Instead you'd wrap that text in some standard element (perhaps `<span>`, or maybe `<strong>`, depending on the semantics of your redness!), and use CSS to change its colour. You'll get the best answers if you tell/show us what you want the end result to be—all the text red on the page? Just a word?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use CSS for this:

```css
.red {
  font-family: arial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="red">
blah
</p>
```

As noted in the comments, use p not font to wrap and style the text

Comment: I wouldn't use the `font` element to do that. It's semantically confusing (and it's possible it wouldn't validate in HTML5, given that [it's non-standard/non-conforming](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font).)

Comment: Good idea @MattGibson I will change it to p